# I am unable to reach the requested skill in Alexa Developer Console

Tags: sinatra, alexa-skills-kit, ngrok

I am running a ruby Sinatra server on my development machine with ngrok.

I have verified that the accessing the publicly exposed url through ngrok does get routed to the ruby server and the correct response is returned.

I also used apitester.com to verify that the exposed url is accessible from the internet and the correct response is returned.

When I attempt to execute using the Alexa Simulator through the alexa developer console I only get "I am unable to reach the requested skill". I get the same response using a physical echo also.

I have double checked the endpoint configuration of the developer console and everything looks like ok to me.

I am using https for the endpoint with the "My development endpoint is a sub-domain of a domain that has a wildcard certificate" as the SSL certificate type.

Using the JSON request that is generated when attempting to use the Alexa Simultor does successfully send the request to my Sinatra server and the appropriate response is returned. This eliminated my concern that this was related to the sinatra/ngrok configuration, but it continues to fail when entering text (or speaking) into the simulator.

This is my first attempt at creating an Alexa skill, so I may be overlooking something obvious.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Solved  I had set the default and North America endpoint urls containing the same URL. Removing the optional North America endpoint url solved the problem for me.

Comment: Please write that as an answer and accept it, instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** 
I had set the default and North America endpoint urls containing the same URL.
Removing the optional North America endpoint url solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for this trick. I tried it and am still getting the failed to reach the skill error but I'm sure I would've ran into this issue next.